# Why CreateProcessAsUser requires interactive window station on Vista/Windows 7?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, windows-vista, process, impersonation

I had to delve into this because the code that worked fine on Windows 2003/XP doesn't on Windows 7. Application launched by the use of CreateProcessAsUser fails with 0xc0000142 error code. The difference between my old code and one available from MSDN at [Starting an Interactive Client Process in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379608(VS.85).aspx) is that I didn't set up privileges and to Window Station and desktop. I've updated my code according to the example, but I would very much like to understand which change in newer Windows made running processes in interactive Window station a requirement?

Comment: The issue remains. I am also looking for a solution. Session 0 isolation is the name of the game. Any process running in session 0 is not able to create GUI instances. The interactive client runs - but no GUI is shown!

Comment: As I said in the post, I just changed my code according to MSDN example. Henry, note that my process was a command-line one, no terminal. So I'm still wondering why do I need an interactive session to run it.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the requirements derive from the change to run interactive processes in a different session from services.  This was done so that applications could not run 'shatter' style attacks against privileged services.  More information is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/vista/services.mspx).

Comment: Yes, I've stumbled upon this when researching the issue. It is not completely relevant to the question though. In a scenario when _ordinary_ executable starts another process using CreateProcessAsUser something different happens on Windows 7 and Windows 2003/XP because on XP process starts successfully and fails with 0xc0000142 on newer OS. Apparently the process doesn't go to interactive session because if I make it to do that according to MSDN example it starts fine. I'm interested in knowing what actually happens and what has changed since XP.